# Setting up MATLAB with a C++ compiler

Tags: c++, matlab, compiler-construction, installation

I'm kind of new to this, and just want to ask. How can I set up MATLAB to work with a C++ compiler. It seems that since I'm running Windows 8.1 as a prerelease, I'm not able to run visual studio 2013. So, I'm thinking of some C++ compiler that I can use when I run `mex -setup'

**Update**

I used [Microsoft Windows SDK for Windows 7 and .NET Framework 4](http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=8279), and selected it as the compiler, and it worked.

Thanks.

Comment: To do what? Build MEX files, standalone library or executable, one of the many Builder targets?

Answer (score 1):

```
mex -setup
```

All is documented here: http://www.mathworks.co.uk/help/matlab/ref/mex.html

The list of supported and compatible compilers for R2013b is here: http://www.mathworks.co.uk/support/compilers/R2013b/index.html

Older releases are linked from this page.

Comment: Making an assumption here... what about `mbuild -setup`? The OP didn't say what he wanted to compile.

Comment: @chappjc True. However, `mex -setup` tends to be the first thing to do to set up a compiler and will address 80% of what users need. Other types of compiler set up are `mbuild -setup` as you point out, compiler for MATLAB and Simulink Coder, etc...

Comment: Don't get me wrong, I agree that the question is probably about MEX file compilation, and your answer is quite helpful with good links. I'll quickly upvote it if the question is clarified.

Comment: Looks like your answer was what the OP needed.  +1

Answer (score 1):

First do you have a C++ compiler installed on your PC? If you do this should work..

```
>>mex -setup

Please choose your compiler for building external interface (MEX) files:
Would you like mex to locate installed compilers [y]/n? n
Select a compiler:
[1] Intel C++ 9.1 (with Microsoft Visual C++ 2005 linker)
[2] Intel Visual Fortran 10.1 (with Microsoft Visual C++ 2005 linker)
[3] Intel Visual Fortran 9.1 (with Microsoft Visual C++ 2005 linker)
[4] Microsoft Platform SDK 14.0
[5] Microsoft Visual C++ 2005
[6] Microsoft Visual C++ 2008
Compiler: 5

The default location for Microsoft Visual C++ 2005 compilers is
C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 8,
1
but that directory does not exist on this machine.
Use C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 8 anyway [y]/n? n
Please enter the location of your compiler:
[C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 8]
E:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 8
Please verify your choices:
Compiler: Microsoft Visual C++ 2005
Location: E:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 8
Are these correct [y]/n? y
Trying to update options file:
C:\Users\fullfanta\AppData\Roaming\MathWorks\MATLAB\R2008a\mexopts.bat
From template: E:\PROGRA~1\MATLAB\R2008a\bin\win64\mexopts\msvc80opts.bat
Done . . .
```